# Why do Replit secrets not work for my Bot Token

Tags: javascript, discord.js, replit

I've got a repl running to keep my Discord.js bot running 24/7. I'm trying to make my token into a Secret Environment thing. I have

`const BOT_TOKEN = process.env['DISCORD_TOKEN']`

written into my code, and then I try to call BOT_TOKEN with

`client.login(BOT_TOKEN)`

the shell is telling me that BOT_TOKEN isn't defined. Any help?

EDIT: `const BOT_TOKEN = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine assuming that your .env file looks something like this `BOT_TOKEN=0123456789`. I think your problem is that you don't have `dotenv` installed. Typing `npm i dotenv` in you console should fix the problem.